# Printing out the integer numbers in ascending order from list of lists that have different lengths

Tags: java

```
public static void ascendingOrder(List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfNums) {
    String result = "";
    int index = 0;

    while (!listOfListOfNums.isEmpty()) {
        int smallestNumber = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfListOfNums.size(); ++i) {
            if (listOfListOfNums.get(i).size() == 0) {
                listOfListOfNums.remove(i);
            } else if (smallestNumber > listOfListOfNums.get(i).get(0)) {
                smallestNumber = listOfListOfNums.get(i).get(0);
                index = i;
            }}
    if(!listOfListOfNums.isEmpty()){
        result += smallestNumber + " ";
       listOfListOfNums.get(index).remove(0);
    }
        }
    System.out.println(result);
```

This is the code I have so far, however, it stops finding the smallest number at some point and just prints out Integer.maxValue().

Comment: It would be better if you can provide your sample list and final expected result.

Comment: Input: [[4,5,6],[7,8,10],[1,3,6][11,22,33],[]].  output: 1,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,10,11,22,33... It would just need to print the numbers out.

Comment: Have a look at some code for Merge Sort, which is in part similar to what you are doing.  It might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using java 8 stream based approach,  
   private static List<Integer> ascendingOrder(List<List<Integer>> listList) {
            return listList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over ALL the integers, every single time, to find the next biggest number. You were only ever checking the first number in each set.

Bear in mind that the approach you're taking is completely destroying the original list!

Fixed code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {       
    List<List<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    data.add(list);
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(7);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(10);
    data.add(list);
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(6);
    data.add(list);
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(11);
    list.add(22);
    list.add(33);
    data.add(list);
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    data.add(list);

    System.out.println("Input:");
    for(List<Integer> l : data) {
      System.out.println(l);
    }
    List<Integer> result = ascendingOrder(data);
    System.out.println("Output:");
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  public static List<Integer> ascendingOrder(List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfNums) {
    int set = 0;
    int index = 0;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    do {
      set = -1;
      index = -1;
      int smallestNumber = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfListOfNums.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> list = listOfListOfNums.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
          int number = list.get(j);
          if (set == -1 || number < smallestNumber) {
            smallestNumber = number;
            set = i;
            index = j;
          }  
        }        
      }
      if(set != -1){
        result.add(smallestNumber);
        listOfListOfNums.get(set).remove(index);
      }
    } while (set != -1);
    listOfListOfNums.clear();
    return result;
  }
```

Example output:

```
Input:
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 10]
[1, 3, 6]
[11, 22, 33]
[]
Output:
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: How would it handle negative numbers? And Thank you very much

Comment: @naomihailu, It would handle them just fine!  The -1 in the code is not being used for comparison of the number values in any way.  The -1 is used to reset the "set" and "index" variables between each run so we know that the first number it encounters becomes the next "smallest" number for comparison against all the rest.  I just put a -1 in for "smallestNumber" to get rid of the compiler warning about using a possibly un-initialized variable.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes so much sense. I was trying to remove the list once the list was empty. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can remove the list when it is empty, but this causes problems as then the stored row for the current smallest number might change. You'd have to account for that as well...